# Excel VBA - increment column reference in range

Tags: vba, excel, increment

How do I increment the column reference in the code below? Just the column ref, the row values can stay the same.

```
Range("w3:w54").PasteSpecial
```

I'm hoping I can do something like this:

```
For i = 23 to 27
'start at column w (which is number 23)

Range(Columns(i)+"3":Columns(i)+"54").PasteSpecial  

Next
```

But that throws an error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Cells(Row, Column)`, so you increment the `Column` part easily with the numeric value, without using a conversion function from Numeric to Alphabetical.

```
For i = 23 To 27
    'start at column w (which is number 23)
    Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(24, i)).PasteSpecial
Next
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Also `...Range("3:24").Columns(i)...` is possible while `paste` will extend the range as it needs to. In most cases also `...Cells(3, i).Paste` will do the job ;)